# Parsing response from TCPSocket

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, minecraft

I'm attempting to create a ruby script that uses a TCPSocket to communicate w/ a Minecraft server and return the name, current number of players, and the maximum number of players. So far I have the following code

```
require 'socket'

class MinecraftServer
  def self.ping(ip, port = 25565)
    server = TCPSocket.new ip, port

    server.write "\xfe"

    response = []
    while line = server.gets
      response << line
    end

    server.close 

    response = response.join

    response
  end
end

puts MinecraftServer.ping('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
```

This gives me something back like `�A Minecraft Server�0�20`. This gives me back all of the information but in a sring when what I would like is a hash. How do I get rid of the odd characters and put the information into a Hash?

Comment: What is the response format like (eg, is it an HTTP server)? Can you post an actual response example?

Comment: It's a minecraft server. I've provided all code that I'm using and the exact string that is returned to me. If you would like to test it for yourself you can do so w/ the IP 192.241.174.210

Comment: You need to implement the protocol.   You can't just say "get rid of the odd characters" without knowing what they mean.  Go learn about the protocol online, break down those "odd characters" into what they mean, and while you're doing it, toss it in a hash if you want.  There's no magic.  Also, go look at the PHP example from your other question for how they do it.

Comment: http://wiki.vg/Protocol  Seems to be a pretty good reference.

Comment: interesting.  it looks lik that php client is woefully out of date and that the ping message is quite a bit more complicated now.  http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of ruby code that does exactly this:

https://gist.github.com/4poc/6281388

It's linked from this page that describes what the protocol is:

http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping